# In a variation of Russian Roulette is it best to go first?

Tags: probability

In a game of Russian Roulette against one other player, lets say you were given the opportunity to shoot 1, 2 or 3 times on your turn. There is 1 bullet and 5 empty chambers in the revolver and once a chamber has been shot, it won't be shot again. The game ends when one player is hit by a round. With the ability to pick how many times you pull the trigger on your turn, is there any advantage in going first?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I understand the rules right, it doesn't matter if you go first or second, and you should always pick just one chamber. 

Imagine a kinder variant of the game where you are playing paintball in a dark room. The one red ball makes you lose and the 5 blue ones are winners. You play the same game but you always go six rounds, then emerge from the dark room and whoever's t-shirt is red loses. Now it's clear you want to have gone only 3 times, and it doesn't matter what order you played in.

Comment: If you alternate, then you win if the bullet is in an even numbered chamber and you lose otherwise, so probability $\frac 12$.  Any scheme in which you will (ultimately) test exactly $3$ chambers will have probability $\frac 12$ for the same reason.  If you were to test $4$ chambers, then your odds of losing increase to $\frac 46=\frac 23$, and so on.  Your best strategy is to test as few chambers as possible.  The order doesn't matter, just the number of chambers your strategy exposes you too.

Comment: Yes they shoot themselves. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @hunter +1 for that *kinder variant*.